# openapi-generator-cliで、すべてのAPIを一つのファイルに出力する方法

Tags: python, openapi, openapi-generator

## 背景

openapi v3で書かれたyamlファイルから、Python3(3.6以上)のClient Libraryを作りたいです。
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

以下のサイトを参考にして、Client Libraryを作成しようとしています。
https://qiita.com/watiko/items/0961287c02eac9211572

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-3.3.4.jar generate --input-spec petstore.yaml --generator-name python --template-dir template/
```

#### 環境

- Xubuntu 18.04
- openapi-generator-cli-3.3.4.jar
- openjdk 10.0.2

## 現状の動き

petstore.yamlに記載されたtagsごとに、pyファイルが`api`ディレクトリに出力されます。

petstore.yaml

```
  /pets/{petId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific pet
      operationId: showPetById
      tags:
        - pet

  /animals/{animalId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific Animal
      operationId: showAnimalById
      tags:
        - animals
```

出力先の`api`ディレクトリの中身

```
animals_api.py
pet_api.py
```

## やりたいこと

`api.py`というファイルに、`tags`関係なく、すべてのapi情報を出力したいです。
以下のように、すべてのAPIに対応したメソッドを、一つのクラスにまとめたいです。

```py
class Api:
    def show_pet_by_id:
        pass

    def show_animal_by_id:
        pass
```

## 質問

「やりたいこと」を実現するには、どうすればよいでしょうか？
apiのテンプレートファイル`api.mustache`には、tagsごとの情報が記載されているので、mustacheファイルだけの修正では難しいように思いました。

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/python/api.mustache

ジェネレータも作成する必要がありますか？

openapi-generatorでの実現が難しい場合は、以下のようなコマンドを実行して、各`*_api.py`を連結します。

```
cat api/*_api.py > api.py && rm *_api.py
```

Comment: ここ [openapi-generator-japanese/Lobby](https://gitter.im/openapi-generator-japanese/Lobby) に質問してみては？

Comment: 日本語版があるのですね。質問してみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんにちは！OpenAPI Generator core teamの中野です。

下記のように、 `tags` の指定を追加するのはどうでしょうか？
（例としてそれぞれに `creatures` を追加しています）

```
  /pets/{petId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific pet
      operationId: showPetById
      tags:
        - pet
+       - creatures

  /animals/{animalId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific Animal
      operationId: showAnimalById
      tags:
        - animals
+       - creatures
```

OpenAPI GeneratorではtagごとにAPIクラスを生成しますので、
上記の場合、 すべてのメソッドが集約された CreaturesApi クラスが生成されます。

ただ、このままですとCreaturesApiの他にPetApi, AnimalsApiも生成されますので
CreaturesApi以外のAPIクラスが不要でしたら、下記のように生成時のオプションを指定することで特定のAPIクラスだけに絞ることができます。

```
$ openapi-generator generate -g python -i {YAML} -o {出力先} \
    -Dapis=creatures \
    -Dmodels \
    -DsupportingFiles
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！1つのAPIは複数のtagを持てるのですね。

Comment: ただswagger.yamlは修正せずに対応したいので、catコマンドを使って連結する案を採用したいと思います。